# getSingleResult did not retrieve any entites - should be fixed (I think so) but it isn't

Tags: java

So I have this code in

PersoanaDao

```
public Optional<PersoanaEntity> get(String username) throws NoResultException {
        return Optional.ofNullable(connection
                .getEntityManager()
                .createQuery("SELECT a FROM PersoanaEntity as a WHERE a.username = :username", PersoanaEntity.class)
                .setParameter("username", username).getSingleResult()
        );
    }
```

and this code in ProcessInput

```
package socket;

import database.daos.PersoanaDao;
import database.models.PersoanaEntity;
import jakarta.persistence.NoResultException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.util.Optional;

public class ProcessInput {
    void processInput(JSONObject data, ObjectOutputStream out) {
        switch (data.get("type").toString())
        {
            case "LOGIN_USER":
                PersoanaDao persoanaDao = new PersoanaDao();
                String username = data.get("username").toString();
                Optional<PersoanaEntity> persoanaEntity = persoanaDao.get(username);
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                if(persoanaEntity.isEmpty()) {
                    try {
                        json.put("status_code", "404");
                        out.writeObject(json.toString());
                        return;
                    }
                    catch(NoResultException noResultException) {
                        try {
                        json.put("status_code", "200");
                        out.writeObject(json.toString());
                        }
                        catch (IOException exception) {
                            System.out.println(exception);
                        }
                    }
                    catch(IOException exception) {
                        System.out.println(exception);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Long story short, the method from PersoanaDao will be called in ProcessInput - but I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" jakarta.persistence.NoResultException: getSingleResult() did not retrieve any entities.
```

and I don't understand why. I specified in the method that it throws NoResultException, and I caught it in my ProcessInput.

I think that this might happen because .getSingleResult is wrapped in that Optional clause - but I'm not really sure. If so, how can I fix my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Check your DB if the record exists or not, you should use getSingleResult() only in case you are 100% sure that a particular record exists in the database (uniquely). The exception thrown is a runtime exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your call to `persoanaDao.get(username);` is out of the try catch block that catches the NoResultException. Refactor your code so that call is in the correct try-catch.